# Powershell false negative inside Register-ObjectEvent

Tags: powershell

This is a real simple question that has me pulling my hair out.

I have an if statement that refuses to work within the action block of a Register-ObjectEvent:

The whole block looks like this:

```
$isCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier CamAction -Action{
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
$AreWeHome = gci $HomeStatus -Recurse | sort LastWriteTime -desc | select -First 1
if ($AreWeHome -eq 'away'){
    Write-Host "MOTION DETECTED: '$CamFolder\$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
}else{
    Write-Host "False Alarm:" $AreWeHome
}
```

}

Look at the if statement:

```
if ($AreWeHome -eq 'away')
```

Now if that statement is false, it executes:

```
Write-Host "False Alarm:" $AreWeHome
```

When I run the PowerShell script, I keep getting this output:

```
False Alarm: away
```

So.. $AreWeHome does actual contain 'away', the if conditions just don't see it that way.

What the heck kind of voodoo is this?

Comment: `'away' -eq $AreWeHome` or `$AreWeHome.Name -eq 'away'`

Comment: Wow.  Thanks.  I knew it was going to be something basic.  That fixed it!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> 'away' `-eq $AreWeHome` or `$AreWeHome.Name -eq 'away'` – Mathias R.

This is the answer provided by [Mathias R. Jensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) in the nested comment above.

Comment: Please don't take another members comment and post it as an answer.

Comment: I can't mark Mathias' response as an answer nested as a comment.  All I can do is upvote or flag the user.